# GitPython Submodule Tree Display

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I'm working with a git repo that has multiple sub-modules beneath. I'm able to walk through the blobs and trees in that folder with no problem, but when I encounter a submodule, I receive the following error: AttributeError: Cannot retrieve the name of a submodule if it was not set initially.

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
from git import Repo
repo = Repo("repo_name")
origin = repo.remotes[0]
ref = origin.refs[0]

tree = ref.commit.tree['devices'] <- devices is a submodule

print tree.name
```

I'm not fully understanding why I cannot access the tree from the submodule. The submodule does exist, and is populated under the .git/modules folder, so which name does it expect to find?

edit: Looks like I've figured out what I've been doing wrong. The Submodule type is a separate repo, so I must treat it as such. In doing so, I must use the submodule.module() to get the proper repo, and then dig down into the tree like I did with my main repo. I was being a little optimistic to think that the tree would abstract all of that away, and keep digging at the submodule like another tree. It did not do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a full description on why Submodule objects retrieved from Trees are not fully functional, see https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/1092
So the short answer: It is a bug/missing feature in GitPython that is still unsolved.